# Ruby on rails - insert dynamic form drop down menu values to table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to insert a drop down menu values to a table named **units** and that drop values are coming from another model named **properties**.

Here is the schema of the units.

```
create_table "units", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "number"
    t.decimal  "monthly_rent"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "property_id"
  end
```

on my view/units/new.html.erb I have this.

```
<% form_for @unit do |f| %>
<%= f.error_messages %>
<p>
    <%= f.label :property_id %>
    <br/>
    <%= select (:unit, :property_id, Property.all.collect  {|property| [property.name,property.id,]}) %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.label :number %>
    <br/>
    <%= f.text_field :number %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.label :monthly_rent %>
    <br/>
    <%= f.text_field :monthly_rent %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

And here is my controller method

```
def create
    @unit = Unit.new(params[:unit])
 # @unit.property_id = 1

    if @unit.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created unit."
      redirect_to @unit
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

Only `number` and `monthy_rent` getting inserted to the table but the `property_id` doesn't come. Can some body help me on this please? Thanks

Comment: Can you add the params hash of the create/update request? It would help track down your problem.

Comment: Hi EmFi, Sorry I have no idea on how to do that, I'm still a beginner for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, sorry guys it was my mistake. It was not working because, `property_id` is not added to the `attr_accessible`, once I added that it worked. but I still don't know the exact issue yet.

```
class Unit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :property
  attr_accessible :number, :monthly_rent, :property_id
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The possible issue I can see from what you've shown us is the errant comma in your select helper. Try rewriting it like this (also using the form helper method):

```
<%= f.select :property_id, Property.all.collect {|property| [ property.name, property.id ] } %>
```

And yes, the output of the create params to your log would help immensely.

Comment: Surprisingly the superfluous comma doesn't cause any problems. Calling select as a method of the form might make a difference, but given, the form declaration, I don't expect it to.

Comment: Good point, trailing commas are totally acceptable in ruby arrays. I don't think that `property` is a reserved/danger word in ruby or rails... got nothing with this code.

Comment: I had a nearly identical response until I realized that. Decided it would make more sense to wait for the params that chase ghosts.

Comment: Hi Ben, thank you for the reply. I tried that but still I get a nil for the property_id 

(rdb:7) @unit.inspect "#<Unit id: 36, number: \"1001\", monthly_rent: #<BigDecimal:7f067f46de80,'0.15E4',9(18)>, created_at: \"2009-11-26 11:25:06\", updated_at: \"2009-11-26 11:25:06\", property_id: nil>" (rdb:7)